# Exceptions with DateTime parsing in RSS feed use SyndicationFeed in c#

Tags: c#, rss

I'm trying to parse Rss2, Atom feeds using  SyndicationFeed objects. But I'm getting XmlExceptions while parsing DateTime field like pubDate

2012-01-17 08:01:06

```
public static List<SyndicationItem> getRssData(string url)
{
    List<SyndicationItem> list = new List<SyndicationItem>();

    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    try
    {
        SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(XmlReader.Create(url));
        list = (from item in feed.Items select item).ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }

    return list;
}
```

The url link http://news.163.com/special/00011K6L/rss_newstop.xml

```
<item id="2">
    <title>...</title>
    <link>...</link>
    <description>......</description>
    <pubDate>2012-01-17 12:09:29</pubDate><-----Exception
</item>
```

Is there a better way to achieve this? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Just out of interest, why are you using a LINQ query expression to get list? It's equivalent to `list = feed.Items.ToList();`. Not part of the problem, but even so... (Likewise, please don't catch exceptions just to throw them again - and if you *do* want to catch and rethrow, just use `throw;` rather than `throw e;`.)

Answer (score 15):

There is a workaround [RSS20FeedFormatter throws exception trying to read some DateTime formats](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2020488).

> To work around this problem, create a custom XML reader that recognizes different date formats. The following is an example of a custom XML reader:

```cs
XmlReader r = new MyXmlReader(url);
SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(r);
Rss20FeedFormatter rssFormatter = feed.GetRss20Formatter();
XmlTextWriter rssWriter = new XmlTextWriter("rss.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
rssWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
rssFormatter.WriteTo(rssWriter);
rssWriter.Close();
```

..and class used in previous code:

```cs
class MyXmlReader : XmlTextReader
{
    private bool readingDate = false;
    const string CustomUtcDateTimeFormat = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"; // Wed Oct 07 08:00:07 GMT 2009

    public MyXmlReader(Stream s) : base(s) { }

    public MyXmlReader(string inputUri) : base(inputUri) { }

    public override void ReadStartElement()
    {
        if (string.Equals(base.NamespaceURI, string.Empty, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) &&
            (string.Equals(base.LocalName, "lastBuildDate", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
            string.Equals(base.LocalName, "pubDate", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
        {
            readingDate = true;
        }
        base.ReadStartElement();
    }

    public override void ReadEndElement()
    {
        if (readingDate)
        {
            readingDate = false;
        }
        base.ReadEndElement();
    }

    public override string ReadString()
    {
        if (readingDate)
        {
            string dateString = base.ReadString();
            DateTime dt;
            if(!DateTime.TryParse(dateString,out dt))
                dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, CustomUtcDateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return dt.ToUniversalTime().ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        else
        {
            return base.ReadString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the feed is an Atom feed (not an RSS feed) you'll need to change this code slightly.  In ReadString(), instead of using the "R" format code, use "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ" which is how the RFC 3339 UTC date format is specified in the .NET Framework's Atom10FeedFormatter.cs class.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, that RSS feed is invalid. If you look at the [RSS 2.0 specification](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html) it states that:

> All date-times in RSS conform to the Date and Time Specification of RFC 822, with the exception that the year may be expressed with two characters or four characters (four preferred).

The string "2012-01-17 12:09:29" doesn't comply to the ["Date and Time" part of RFC 822](http://asg.web.cmu.edu/rfc/rfc822.html#sec-5). It should be "17 01 2012 12:09:29" or something similar.