# Parsing a DateTime value in the SyndicationFeed

Tags: c#, datetime, rss, atom-feed

I'm using below code for parsing an atom feed:

```
using(var reader = new MyXmlReader("http://tutsplus.com/courses.atom")) {

    var doc = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
    var newFeed = new AtomFeed {
        Id = doc.Id,
        Title = doc.Title.Text,
        Url = url,
        UpdateDate = DateTime.Now
    };
    XNamespace dc = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
    newFeed.AtomEntries = (from entry in doc.Items
    select new AtomEntry {
        Id = entry.Id,
        Links = entry.Links,
        Title = entry.Title.Text,
        Content = entry.Content.ToString(),
        PublishDate = entry.PublishDate.DateTime,
        UpdatedDate = entry.LastUpdatedTime.DateTime,
        Authors = entry.Authors
    }).ToList();

}
```

Seems that a string was not recognized as a valid DateTime in my feed. I'm also aware ([+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891047/exceptions-with-datetime-parsing-in-rss-feed-use-syndicationfeed-in-c-sharp)) that The `SyndicationFeed.Load` method expects to receive feeds that are in standard format like this: `Mon, 05 Oct 2015 08:00:06 GMT`. So I created my [custom XML reader](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2020488) that recognizes different date formats. But still have same error!
Any idea?

Comment: "But still have same error" doesn't really tell us much about what you've observed with your code. Have you debugged into it? Is it parsing the dates correctly? Personally I'd avoid using something which *expects* RSS to read Atom... surely there are proper Atom readers out there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried it, with your linked custom XML reader, I also got this error when it came to parsing the "published" and "updated" dates. Looking at the code for the `Atom10FeedFormatter` class, it is trying to parse dates in these formats (`DateFromString` method)

```
    const string Rfc3339LocalDateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz";
    const string Rfc3339UTCDateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ";
```

http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/WCF/WCF/3@5@30729@1/untmp/Orcas/SP/ndp/cdf/src/NetFx35/System@ServiceModel@Web/System/ServiceModel/Syndication/Atom10FeedFormatter@cs/2/Atom10FeedFormatter@cs

So I changed in the `MyXmlReader` implementation to set that format `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ`, then all is well with this date parsing (I also had to change in `ReadStartElement` the element names to set `readingDate` equal to true, i.e. published and updated).

```
public override string ReadString()
{
    if (readingDate)
    {
        string dateString = base.ReadString();
        DateTime dt;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dt))
            dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, CustomUtcDateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        return dt.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    else
    {
        return base.ReadString();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but still have same problem, Can you provide more information.

Comment: No, that was it for me. If you put a breakpoint at `return dt.ToUniversalTime()...` is it being hit when `Syndication.Load` is executing? If not then it is not doing anything and you need to provide the full implementation of `MyXmlReader`. Also, is the error now exactly the same as before?