# Error parsing RSS feed with C#/Mono on Mac using SyndicationFeed.Load()

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mono, rss, xamarin-studio

I'm running the following code on both Windows and OSX, parsing the same source:

```
XmlReader r = new XmlReader(feedURI);
SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(r);
```

Both Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio work like a charm on Windows. Xamarin Studio on Mac fails on the second line. The exception thrown is related to the parsing of "pubDate" XML field (while lastBuildDate, which is in the same format, works).

The feed I'm trying to parse is at the following url: http://www.tntvillage.scambioetico.org/rss.php?c=0&p=10

I tried fixing this by inheriting XmlTextReader in a custom class as shown here:

[Exceptions with DateTime parsing in RSS feed use SyndicationFeed in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891047/exceptions-with-datetime-parsing-in-rss-feed-use-syndicationfeed-in-c-sharp)

with no luck.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: can you post the full exception?

Comment: And an example of the feed

Answer (score 0):

[Argotic](https://argotic.codeplex.com/) library does the trick, works on both .NET Framework and Mono with the latter not throwing any exception when executed on Mac OSX environment.